# Need help to customize a class attribute in ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, rspec, attributes

I am trying to create a Book class, with 1 attribute: title, which must be capitalize if entering in lowercase. My code works in repl.it but rspec still show NoMethodError (undefined method 'title' for #(Book.... @title="Inferno")
My code:

```
class Book
    def initialize(title=nil)
        @title = title
    end
    def title=(new_title)
        title = new_title.capitalize!

    end

end
```

Rspec:

```
require 'book'

describe Book do

  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class Book
  def initialize(title=nil)
    @title = title
  end

  def title=(new_title)
    title = new_title.capitalize!
    puts title
    puts @title
  end

  def title
    @title
  end

end

b = Book.new('hello')
b.title = 'hello'

--output:--
Hello
hello
```

@title and title are two different variables.

Comment: It works, thanks but can you explain why I need to def title 1 more time?

Comment: The `title=()` method allows you to set the @title instance variable.  The `title()` method lets you retrieve the @title instance variable, which you may or may not want to allow.  Typically, `title=()` and `title()` are both needed.

Comment: >>"@title and title are two different variables" I thought @title is a variable and title is the input value.

Comment: What do you mean by 'input value'?  If you mean the method's parameter variable, you named the parameter variable `new_title` in your code.  Whenever you write `var_name = ....` inside a method, that creates a new variable, `var_name`, that will be destroyed when the method ends.

Comment: ...so what you needed to write was `@title = new_title.capitalize()`. What you actually did was create a new variable called `title`, you assigned a value to `title`, and then the method ended, and the `title` variable was destroyed.  On the other hand, @variables are special variables and they are not destroyed when a method ends.

Answer (score 0):

try this out.

```
class Book

  attr_reader :title

    def initialize(title=nil)
      @title = title && title.capitalize!
    end

    def title=(new_title)
        @title = new_title && new_title.capitalize!
    end

end
```